# Odd fan speed show in Speedfan

Tags: fan, speedfan

I just made some maintenance to my computer. The fans were replaced.

When I check the temperature with Speedfan, there is an odd fan speed showing up.

Should I check the fan? Or it is a bad detection?

I have 1 12cm front fan and 12cm back fan on the case. Both of them are connected to the plugs from PSU. ( No intervention from the motherboard ). And I have a cpu cooler too.

Now I don't know which fan it is talking about.

[image]

Comment: Just open the case and peak at the fan.

Comment: I've already opened it. All fans are spinning nicely. What troubles me most is the fact that even if I unplug the power cable to the rear fan, the readings didn't change a bit. I suspect the rear and front fans were not monitor. Which fans are fan1 and fan2?

Comment: Your fans are NOT in any way connected to your mobo? Then that program would have no idea what speed your fans are running at.

Comment: bad detection..